# Water from toilet tank goes straight down the drain?

Tags: toilet

Is it possible for the tank water to bypass the bowl and straight to the drain?  Would this mean I need a new toilet?

The toilet was running and I have been trying to fix the flush valve.

Mansfiled toilet.

Comment: How do you know it’s bypassing the bowl?

Comment: I don't think you need a new toilet. Perhaps you need to contact a handyman to fix the toilet.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely a bad flap, probably not seating correctly on the bottom of your tank. this can cause the water to constantly flow straight into your bowl and as the bowl fills up it will automatically drain. Try cleaning it or replacing it.

Comment: How would this allow water to bypass the bowl?

Comment: The question was not very detailed so I'm assuming that the water is bypassing the flap and into the bowl, therefore draining and possibly giving the illusion of bypassing the bowl. Some models I've seen let water into the bowl without much water disturbance so it could appear that water is going straight to the drain, but in most cases this wouldn't really be possible

Answer (score 1):

No water can not bypass bowl. The bowl is connect to the drain. The cistern is connect to the water supply. The only way to get to the drain is through the bowl.

Comment: I think water can bypass the bowl if there is a defect or damage to the toilet. The inflow of water from the tank comes pretty close to the drain past the trap on most toilets I've seen. A small crack or hole could be present. I think it would be best to establish that the water is in fact bypassing the bowl before providing advice. Perhaps they put food coloring into the tank, shut off the water, and watched it slowly drop, but the bowl water never changed colors. In either case, the flapper would be allowing water past it, so that should be fixed.